# Scaling X Axis Values

Tags: r, function, plot

I am trying to plot the function described below. However, when I do plot it, the x-axis shows 0 up to 1000, probably due to my definition of x0, instead of 0 up to 10. However, if I just use 1:10 as my x-values, the plot is not smooth at all. My question is: how do I set the x-axis to give me the real values that correspond to the function at that point?

PS: I have seen solutions where people replace the x-axis fully with their own values, but I am looking for a method that just uses the actual values of x.

```
eq <- function(x){
  4*x^3 - 72*x^2 + 288*x
}

x0 <- seq(1, 10, by = 0.01)

plot(eq(x0),type='l',main="Plot of 4*x^3 - 72*x^2 + 288*x", xlab = "x", ylab = "4*x^3 - 72*x^2 + 288*x")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed your `x0` values. R deduced the `x` values based on the number of elements in `eq(x0)` (A sequence `1:1000` was used by default). By the way, you can improve your labels with `expression`

```
plot(x = x0, 
     y = eq(x0),
     type='l',
     main=expression(paste("Plot of ", 4*x^3 - 72*x^2 + 288*x)), 
     xlab = expression(x), 
     ylab = expression(4*x^3 - 72*x^2 + 288*x))
```

It works fine

[image]

Comment: Upvote but maybe `main = expression(paste("Plot of ",  4 * x^3 - 72 * x^2 + 288 * x))` and `ylab = expression(4 * x^3 - 72 * x^2 + 288 * x)` would be nicer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)